# Context in jasmine describe

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine

Lets say I have simple describe in jasmine.

```
describe('MyDescribe', () => {
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

    beforeEach...
    afterEach...

    it('Should do something', () => {
    console.log(this);
    }
   
}
```

But `this` is `undefined`.
Why is it undefined? Why it does not contains stuff from describe?

Comment: Because you're using an arrow function. Use a regular function instead.